# Passing an argument to a callback block

Tags: ruby, block

I'm writing a simple callback for a gem I'm working on. Please note that due to certain architectural constraints, I can't use the ActiveSupport `define_callbacks` method for this specific case.

Right now, I have something like this:

```
def self.after_data_transcoding(&block)
  define_method :_after_data_transcoding_callback { block.call }
end
```

So an use case is similar to this:

```
class MyClass
  after_data_transcoding do
  end
end
```

The actual call is done by `instance.send(:_after_data_transcoding_callback)`.

The code so far works great. I would have liked to go one step further and be able access the response as a block argument:

```
class MyClass
  after_data_transcoding do |response|
    # Do something with the response
  end
end
```

However, I haven't had much success. Any thoughts on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was easier than I thought.

```
define_method(:_after_data_transcoding_callback) { |response| 
  block.call(response) 
}

instance.send(:_after_data_transcoding_callback, response)
```